# How do I replace values with symbols appended to the end of it with NaN in a Pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I am trying to clean my pandas dataset, however I can't figure out a way to remove the weird values with #,*,x appended at the end of the value. I would like to replace all those values with np.nan.

I have attached a link below of how my dataset looks like.

https://imgur.com/gallery/5l5XhF1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) for get only numeric columns, then [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) because [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) working with each column (`Series`) separately for replace non numeric to `NaN`s with `errors='coerce'` parameter:

```
non_num_cols = ['date']
df = df.set_index(non_num_cols).apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').reset_index()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pandas to_numeric](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) - make sure you add `errors=coerce`.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1 : you want to replace junk with the cleaned values**

```
replace_dict = {
        '#': '',
        '*': ''
    }

for key in replace_dict.keys():
    df = df.applymap(lambda x: x.replace(key, replace_dict[key]) if type(x) is str else x)
```

**Option 2 : you want to replace junk with np.nan**

```
import pandas
import re

replace_char = ['#', '*']
for char in replace_char:
    df = df.applymap(lambda x: np.nan if re.search('.*' + char, str(x)) else x)
```

Comment: Thanks alot for replying, I was wondering how I could instead replace the record with Nan rather than removing just the symbol. Since those values are abnormally high relative to the column